# Save database storage or save queries accesing to multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, storage, backend

I am considering the structural database´s design of the following specific problem:

I have 2 different tables belonging to the same database. In the first table the detailed data of different objects is stored, where the column id refers to the the specific object.

On the other hand, the second table stores every single change that the objects in the first table have perceived. Every single row in our second table stores as well the id referencing to the object as the version_id which defines the different state versions of the objects, that is every single change effectuated.

Now let´s say the 'eliminated' parameter is set to "true" in a row of `objects` table for declaring an object as not visible in the object´s manager site. In our display site the table `version` is accesed for showing a linked object´s version, nevertheless the system shouldn´t display it if the object refered by `id` is marked as eliminated.

For solving this problem, I have two possible solutions: either increment the database storage, adding an `eliminated` column to the`version` table, or I add a query in php for processing the parameter `eliminated` from the `objects` table after receiving the object `id` from the `version` table.

I want to know which disadvantage and advantage are presented in both different solutions, if saving storage cost would be prefarable than processing more queries and accesing multiple queries for receiving the data, or if contrary sacrificing storage cost and spreading the `eliminated` column into the `version` table leads to a better response time performance of the site by sparing multiple queries for accesing data from other tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `objects` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `eliminated`  tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  ...

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `version` (
 `version_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `object_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `eliminated`  tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL, //optional
  ...

  PRIMARY KEY (`version_id`),
 KEY `id` (`version_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Side note:  A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `KEY`, so do not redundantly say `KEY(id)`.

Comment: And change `version` to `PRIMARY KEY(object_id, version_id), INDEX(version_id)` for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of adding an eliminated column to the version table is that it provides you with details of the object elimination. It allows you to store details of the elimination for the object.

The drawback is that you are saving an extra row and also adding an extra column, which can create an overhead if there are a lot of rows in the table.

Which solution you use depends on how much data is being stored in your tables and also what data needs to be displayed to the user